# AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last) on Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am receiving this error when I am coding on Python.
Versions: 
Python 3
Numpy 1.4

```
import numpy as np
a = np.aray([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
print(a + 5)
print("------------")
print(a - 3)
print("------------")
print(a * 3)
print("------------")
print(a / 0.25)
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Change `np.aray` to `np.array`, this is a typo.

Comment: Since this is a rather obvious error, I'm assuming you do not use a IDE, only some sort of  text editor? I'd highly recommend using to a program with syntax and error highlighting, it will make your live much easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a syntax error. Try to write `np.array` instead of `np.aray`